# SSIS Package Does Not Execute In SQL Server 2014 ProtectionLevel: EncryptSensitiveWIthUserKey

Tags: sql-server, ssms

My boss wants me to figure out a problem we are facing. The problem is that we have a SSIS Project we built using Microsoft SQL Server data tools and are trying to execute that package on SQL Server 2014 Management studio.

It is listed under the SQL Server Agent as a Job and when we execute the job, we get an error: **Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user '********'."**

In our SSIS properties under security, our protection level is "EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey". I've done a ton of research and it shows to either change that property to "Don'tSaveSensitive", which we need to save the password, or creating a user proxy to serve as a median across the platforms.

We are able to execute the project on the SQL Server Data Tools interface, but not when uploading the Job onto SQL Server 2014 Management Studio. We believe it's because the login is failing as stated in the error above.

How would I go about connecting the two platforms together? Would a user proxy work for this case?

I am still new to this, so please correct any errors I have above kindly.

Comment: Please note I have tried adding a new proxy but I get an error message "Proxy "1*******" is not a valid Windows user. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 14529).

Answer (score 0):

When you use encrypt with user key that means that when the developer on the current machine, using the current login info, SSIS will decrypt everything when the package is opened by the developer on the same machine. To use the package on another machine you should use another setting such as EncryptSensitiveWithPassword.

Comment: I do have it as EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey. We are not using the package on another machine, all in one machine.

Comment: Is it the same user login?

Comment: User login for what exactly? The computer itself? Or the sa login?

Comment: The computer login at the machine level.